# how can i get friends list from facebook friendspickercontroller

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

In my Iphone app i'm using facebook sdk 3.1. I want to redirect facebook login page first. after login again redirect to my app.

And also i want to get facebook friends list from friendspickercontroller when i don't login facebook in settings in iphone.

i'm using this code

Facebook login:

```
-(IBAction)facebookButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
NSLog(@" hi im ");

NSArray *permissions =
[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"user_photos", @"friends_photos",@"email", nil];

[FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:permissions
                                   allowLoginUI:YES
                              completionHandler:
 ^(FBSession *session,
   FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {

     if(!error)
     {
         NSLog(@" hi im sucessfully lloged in");
         [self sessionStateChanged:session state:state error:error];
     }
 }];

}


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
        openURL:(NSURL *)url
sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
     annotation:(id)annotation
{
   return [FBSession.activeSession handleOpenURL:url];
}


- (void)sessionStateChanged:(FBSession *)session
                  state:(FBSessionState) state
                  error:(NSError *)error
{

  switch (state) {
    case FBSessionStateOpen:
    {
        UIViewController *topViewController =
        [appDelegate.naviCon topViewController];
        if ([[topViewController modalViewController]
             isKindOfClass:[ViewController class]]) {
            [topViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        }
        NSLog(@"h im in state open 1111111");
        {
           NSLog(@"hi iam in open state9999999999999999999");
        }
    }
        break;
    case FBSessionStateClosed:
      {
          NSLog(@"iam in loginfailed 444444444444");
      }
    case FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed:
          NSLog(@"iam in loginfailed 555555555555");

        NSLog(@"iam in statecloze 555555555555");
        [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
        break;
    default:
        break;
}

if (error)
{

}
}
```

Getting frieds:

```
 NSArray *permissions =
    [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"user_photos", @"friends_photos",@"email", nil];

    if([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook])
    {            
        [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:permissions allowLoginUI:YES    completionHandler: ^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error)
        {
            if(!error)
            {
if (self.friendPickerController == nil)
            {
                self.friendPickerController = [[FBFriendPickerViewController alloc] init];
                self.friendPickerController.title = @"Pick Friends";
                self.friendPickerController.delegate = self;
            }
            [self.friendPickerController loadData];
            //[self.friendPickerController clearSelection];
            [self presentModalViewController:self.friendPickerController animated:YES];
}
}];
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you also need read_friendlists permission for getting friend list.

then use

```
-(void)friendPickerViewControllerSelectionDidChange:(FBFriendPickerViewController *)friendPicker
{

 NSArray *friends = friendPicker.selection;

}
```

Thanks

Comment: i am not loking for this. I want to get friends list when i'm not login facebook in settings in iphone.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)friendPickerViewControllerSelectionDidChange:(FBFriendPickerViewController *)friendPicker
{
 NSArray *friends = friendPicker.selection;
}
```

I hope that's what you're looking for!

Comment: i am not loking for this. I want to get friends list when i'm not login facebook in settings in iphone.

Comment: You can't get any info from Facebook if the person isn't logged into an account.